# Sql Query "%s: invalid identifier" Exception

Tags: sql, oracle

I write a query, that's join two table. But I am already taken 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" for the paid. 
That's my query

```
SELECT za.TAH_DONEM,
    za.ABONE_ID,
    za.URUN_ID,
    za.ID,
    za.TARIFE_ID,
    tp.tarıfe_gecerlık_ıd,
    (select sum(ucret) from schemaName.TARIFE_Fas f where f.xx_id=tp.xx_id and f.ucret_turu_id!=11400) AS paid
FROM schemaName.Z_ABONE_URUN za 
INNER JOIN schemaName.TARIFE_PLAN tp 
ON za.TARIFE_ID = tp.TARIFE_ID 
where za.tah_donem=201905 and paid=0;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference a column from the outer query like that, but you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT za.TAH_DONEM,
    za.ABONE_ID,
    za.URUN_ID,
    za.ID,
    za.TARIFE_ID,
    tp.tarıfe_gecerlık_ıd,
    (
       SELECT SUM(ucret) 
       FROM schemaName.TARIFE_Fas f 
       WHERE f.xx_id=tp.xx_id AND f.ucret_turu_id != 11400
     ) AS paid
  FROM schemaName.Z_ABONE_URUN za INNER JOIN schemaName.TARIFE_PLAN tp ON za.TARIFE_ID = tp.TARIFE_ID 
  WHERE za.tah_donem = 201905
)tmp WHERE tmp.paid=0;
```